# HTTPS API calls in Angular11

Tags: angular, https, angular-http, angular11

I've built an Angular application with my coworkers making an ASP.NET backend API that I will call to access data.

In the beginning, we've used the *HTTP* link for communication but now the backend team changed it to use **HTTPS** (deployed over IIS).
Now we have a net::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID error when we try to access **HTTPS** links.

I've read articles about installing needed certificates locally on the machine, but is it possible to somehow create some sort of Keystore that will be prebuilt in Web App that the App will use for certification?

Any answer or clarification is very welcome since we are still learning what we are doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your backend team just needs to buy a trusted certificate for the IIS. If they use a self signed one, you will have to explicitly trust it on your local machine